# Search in a reference text field with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this Schema

```
var users = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    following: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "users"}]
});
users.index({name: 'text'});
```

I want to use Mongoose to find users who they have **"john"** in their name and they are exists in following array of user of _id = x

in other way if it was SQL the query would be (it just example to illustrate the relations)

```
SELECT * FROM users where _id = x AND users.following.name LIKE '%john%'
```

I think that if following array was embedded in the user collections it would be easy to make.

How can i handle that in mongoose ?

Comment: With aggregation. Look at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-lookup hot to do 1-to-many joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html
I used **populate** with **match**

```
.findById("x", {following: 1}).populate({ path: 'following',match: {$text: {$search: "john"}}})
```